# Gremlin Vertex id vs label: advantages?

Tags: gremlin

I am designing a graph, and see examples where several vertices will have a similar label, such as 'user', etc.  When knowing its unique value, one can assign it to the vertex' id, and look it up as:

```
g.V('person').has('id','unique-value'). ...
```

Or assign that unique value as a label, and reference it that way.

```
g.V('unique-value'). ...
```

Is there a particular reason not use unique values (an id, essentially) as a label, such as performance?  What is the best strategy for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question and your Gremlin examples don't quite align. I think that you mean to compare:

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').has(T.id,'unique-value')
```

and

```
g.V('unique-value')
```

Note my corrections in that first Gremlin statement. `V()` does not take a vertex label as an argument - it can only take a vertex `id` or a `Vertex` object. Also, the actual vertex identifier must be referenced by `T.id` and not `'id'`, the latter being a reference to a user-defined property named "id". `T.id` is what you get returned from `g.V().id()`. We often refer to `T.id` as just `id` and I will do so going forward.

With that being straightened out, there is no need to do `hasLabel('person')` if you have the `id` handy, so the two examples above return the same value and I would think that most graph databases would likely optimize away the label filter and just use the `id` for their lookup so I wouldn't imagine that you'd see a difference in performance, but for readability purposes I'd stick to just using `V('unique-value')`.

Your question specifically asked about using a unique label as a way to identify a vertex, so I will also address that. A label is not meant for unique identification of a graph element. It is meant to categorize groups of elements. Aside from that convention, I think there are a number of technical reasons not to do that. Some graphs have limits on the number of labels you can have so that could be a problem depending on your graph provider. At the very least, you reduce the portability of your code by doing that. I think it would impact performance as `label` lookups are not going to be as fast as `id` lookups (especially as you scale the graph up in size).

Comment: Seems I was indeed off with my syntax, think I looked at too many .addV('label-name') samples.  Thanks!